# How to link statically to wxWidgets from Kdevelop on linux?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, static-linking, kdevelop

Hello I have installed wxWidget-3.1.0 s on windows it works fine using it from MSVC++. But On Linux fedora 27 I built it in a sub-directory "wxWidget3.1.0/build-gtk-unicode-release".

These are the comands:

```
../configure --disable-debug
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Above it generates for me a release shared library I get around building programs upon it. So I easily use "`wx-config --cxxflags --libs`". For Ides like Eclipse, Codeblocks, Kdevelop.

The problem is I need some "static version" of the library so I created another sub-directory: "wxWidgets-3.1.0/build-gtk-static-release-unicode" So I issued the commands:

```
../configure --disable-debug --disable-shared --enable-unicode
make
sudo make install
```

- I created a project with Codeblocks and it compiles easily with adding only "`wx-config --cxxflags --libs`"
- When it comes to Eclipse CDT I used `wx-config --cxxflags` for the compiler and `wx-config --libs` for the linker. But it fails complaining
  about "Unreferenced defeinition of the APIs".
- After a long search I Find a tricky workaround:

  ```
  Project->Properties->C/C++->GCC C++ Linker->Experts settings:

  ${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}
  ```

So I made the "Flags" at the end to become:

```
    ${COMMAND} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS} ${FLAGS}
```

And it works fine.

*** The problem:

I'd like to configure Kdevelop for wxWidgets as a static library keep in mind as a dynamic library I managed to do that. So My Configurations are:

From Kdevelop->Project->Open Configuration->CMake File->CXX_COMPILER_FLAGS I enters:

The result of `wx-config --cxxflags` in a terminal.

And for the linker:

```
    CXX_LNKER_FLAGS:
```

The reult of `wx-config --libs`

But The code compiles but doesn't build I don't have "expert settings" as in Eclipse CDT.

Can anyone solve how to link to wxWidgets from Kdevelop statically?

Thank you for this boring long story. NB: I Added What problems I faced and what did to get around them to help people who face the same problems. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Kdevelop just wraps cmake these days, so your best bet is to see what cmake is doing.  Go to your build directory and run `make VERBOSE=1` or `ninja -v` (depending on how your project was configured).

Comment: @StephenNewell: I see in the Kdevelop "Verbose=1" by default.

Comment: @Maestro, out of curiosity why do you need KDevelop, if you have a working configuration for C::B and Eclipse? People usually have only one IDE they are working with. Also, it is very unusual to set up static linking in *mix world. Why do you need it?

Comment: @Igor: Thank you! I'll stick to eclipse and codeblocks. And I rebuild my `dynamic` version of the library.